# form_tag garbles my text_field with HTML5 data attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this code working in a separate view, but with inside of a form_for

```
<%= text_field :search_tags, :id => 'search_tags', 'data-autocomplete' => "lame sauce" %>
```

What I'm trying to do is create a simple form for form submission with autocomplete. It works great in the other location, but for some reason, as soon as I take this text_field out of form_for it generates this HTML:

```
<input id="search_tags_{:id=&gt;&quot;search_tags&quot;, &quot;data-autocomplete&quot;=&gt;&quot;lame sauce&quot;}" name="search_tags[{:id=&gt;&quot;search_tags&quot;, &quot;data-autocomplete&quot;=&gt;&quot;lame sauce&quot;}]" size="30" type="text">
```

It's all garbled and ugly :(
Now, because this is a simple form I'm submitting I was just using form_tag, I just need it to go to a specific controller and action... that's it. 
Anyway, I've read through the text_field_tag and text_field docs, and it seems that neither does quite what i'd like it to do. What is a good solution to this problem? Or is there some way of using text_field or text_field_tag, that I'm not aware of? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, is only a problem in the way you used the text_field, try this:

```
<%= text_field :search, :tags, :id => 'search_tags', 'data-autocomplete' => "lame sauce" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Outside of `form_for`, you need to specify *both an object name and then a method name* as the first and second arguments if you want to use `text_field` and not `text_field_tag`.

In case you decide to go with `text_field_tag` (which is probably better for your purposes when you are outside of a `form_for`), make sure that you use the proper syntax: the first argument is the id, and the rest is the options hash.

References: [RoR API: FormHelper#text_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field), [RoR API](http://api.rubyonrails.org)

P.S. You don't really need to override the id like that -- it defeats part of the purpose of `form_for`, which generates RESTful-style forms.

Answer (score 1):

First parameter is the id, second parameter is the value.
Needs to look something like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag "search_tags", '', 'data-autocomplete' => "lame sauce" %>
```